# How can I compare elements in an array and declare if they're in the right spot or not?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const listOfWords = ['angel', 'break', 'clear', 'knock', 'maybe'];

var userWord = readLine("Enter a 5 letter word: \n");

var randomItem = listOfWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*listOfWords.length)];

var newWord = userWord;

var randomItem;

letterChecker();
```

The "is yellow" statement should only be displayed if the letter is in the array, but not in that spot, and the "is grey" should only be placed if the character isn't in the array at all but neither work as they should. When you type in a 5 letter word, the corresponding character such as [0], [1], [2], [3], [4] should compare, however this isn't the case. For context I have the same if statement below after the other but every [] is the next number up. They are all within the same function I just didn't add it so it didn't take up space.

```
function letterChecker() {
println(randomItem);
  
  if(newWord[0] === randomItem[0]) {
            console.log(newWord[0] + " is green");
    } else {
        if(newWord.includes(randomItem[0])){
            console.log(newWord[0] + " is yellow");
        }
    }
    if(!newWord.includes(randomItem[0])){
            console.log(newWord[0] + " is grey");
    }
    
    
    if(newWord[1] === randomItem[1]) {
            console.log(newWord[1] + " is green");
    } else {
        if(newWord.includes(randomItem[1])){
            console.log(newWord[1] + " is yellow");
        }
    }
    if(!newWord.includes(randomItem[1])){
            console.log(newWord[1] + " is grey");
    }
    
    
    if(newWord[2] === randomItem[2]) {
            console.log(newWord[2] + " is green");
    } else {
        if(newWord.includes(randomItem[2])){
            console.log(newWord[2] + " is yellow");
        }
    }
    if(!newWord.includes(randomItem[2])){
            console.log(newWord[2] + " is grey");
    }
    
    
    if(newWord[3] === randomItem[3]) {
            console.log(newWord[3] + " is green");
    } else {
        if(newWord.includes(randomItem[3])){
            console.log(newWord[3] + " is yellow");
        }
    }
    if(!newWord.includes(randomItem[3])){
            console.log(newWord[3] + " is grey");
    }
       
        
    if(newWord[4] === randomItem[4]) {
            console.log(newWord[4] + " is green");
    } else {
        if(newWord.includes(randomItem[4])){
            console.log(newWord[4] + " is yellow");
        }
    }
    if(!newWord.includes(randomItem[4])){
            console.log(newWord[4] + " is grey");
    }
```

}

The first word is the word I input into the readline() and the second word is the randomized word. This is the output:

```
Enter a 5 letter word: 
angel
break
a is grey
Enter another word: 
break
r is yellow
Enter another word: 
break
e is green
Enter another word: 
break
a is green
Enter another word: 
break
k is green
```

Expexted Output:

```
Enter a 5 letter word: 
    angel
    break
    a is yellow
    Enter another word: 
    break
    r is green
    Enter another word: 
    break
    e is green
    Enter another word: 
    break
    a is green
    Enter another word: 
    break
    k is green
```

Code output:

```
ReferenceError: i is not defined
    at letterChecker (17:10)
    at 12:1
Enter a 5 letter word: 
angel
randomItemknock
```

Comment: Why do you declare `userWord` and `randomItem` twice each?

Comment: What is `readLine()`?

Comment: @user1599011 readLine() is where the program allows the user to input a string. In this case, the readline asks me to enter a word, then the array becomes that string

Comment: Please include that function here so that we can debug with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @user1599011 updated, however readline() isn't a function in the application im using(codeHS) it's a built in feature

Comment: Okay, can you include an example of what it might return? Hard to debug otherwise.

Comment: What's your expected output for the example you give above?

Comment: I posted the expected output. Essentially, I want for the "is yellow" to display if the letter is in the array but not in the right spot, grey if the letter isn't in the array at all, and green if the letter is in the right spot(which already works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have your `includes` backwards; you're checking that the user's word includes a particular letter from the random word, whereas you *should* be checking that the random word contains the letter from the user's word.

```js
const listOfWords = ['angel', 'break', 'clear', 'knock', 'maybe'];

//var userWord = readLine("Enter a 5 letter word: \n");
var userWord = "angel";

var randomItem = listOfWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*listOfWords.length)];

var newWord = userWord;

var randomItem;

letterChecker();

function letterChecker() {
console.log("randomItem",randomItem);
  
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log("newWord[i]",newWord[i]);
    console.log("randomItem[i]",randomItem[i]);
    console.log("equal?",newWord[i] === randomItem[i]);
    console.log(randomItem + " includes '" + newWord[i] + "'?",randomItem.includes(newWord[i]));
    if(newWord[i] === randomItem[i]) {
              console.log(newWord[i] + " is green");
      }
      else {
          if(randomItem.includes(newWord[i])){//words reversed
              console.log(newWord[i] + " is yellow");
          }
      }
      if(!randomItem.includes(newWord[i])){
           console.log(newWord[i] + " is grey");
      }
      console.log("---")
   }
}
```

Comment: You're right I had those two variables backwards. Thank you